getComputedStyle and getBoundingClientRect give different width results when the element is scaled
After applying scale on an element, the width of the child elements calculated by getComputedStyle and getBoundingClientRect are different, why does this happen and which value is correct?
Here is a minimal implementation:
https://codepen.io/lai9fox/pen/wvVMyOq


const child = document.getElementById("child");
const getComputedStyleWidth = getComputedStyle(child).width;
const getBoundingClientRectWidth = child.getBoundingClientRect().width;

const span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerText = `
  width for getComputedStyle: ${getComputedStyleWidth}
  width for getBoundingClientRect: ${getBoundingClientRectWidth}
  `;
document.body.appendChild(span);
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#child {
  background: yellow;
}
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <div id="child">
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




getComputedStyle returns all the CSS properties. The property width has value 500px, that hasn't been changed by your code. getBoundingClientRect returns the smallest rectangle which includes the element. When you apply scale(2) that will have width 1000px. See MDN for descriptions.

To expand on what @AHaworth has stated above, both values are correct. Do you have a specific issue with this implementation? If so, please edit the question to provide details.
